HAVING Count clauses with conditions?
Say I have a table with orders stored in it. Those orders have an OrderType column indicating what kind of order it is.
Those orders also have a column indicating which orders should be grouped together (OrderGroup).
I now need to find OrderGroups that have two OrderTypes of 3845 AND one OrderType of 5188.
I built my normal query with the GROUP BY like this:
SELECT  OrderGroup
FROM    dbo.Order orders
GROUP BY orders.OrderGroup
ORDER BY orders.OrderGroup

But now that I need to add the criteria for the OrderType rows, I am a but stumped. This is the logic I am looking for (not real SQL):
SELECT  OrderGroup
FROM    dbo.Order orders
GROUP BY orders.OrderGroup
HAVING (COUNT(orders.OrderType) = 2 WHEN orders.OrderType = 3845)
       AND (COUNT(orders.OrderType) = 1 WHEN orders.OrderType = 5188)
ORDER BY orders.OrderGroup

Is there a way to do something like this in SQL Server 2019?

HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN OrderType = 3845 THEN 1 END )  = 2 AND COUNT( CASE WHEN OrderType = 5188 THEN 1 END ) = 1

Search "conditional aggregation".

You could do where OrderType in (3845, 5188) group by OrderGroup having sum(OrderType) = 12878 Well, I guess that would probably be frowned upon...

You need to create count expressions to conditionally count the relevant orders, and then compare those to the expected counts:
SELECT   OrderGroup
FROM     dbo.Order orders
GROUP BY orders.OrderGroup
HAVING   COUNT(CASE orders.OrderType WHEN 3845 THEN 1 END) = 2 AND
         COUNT(CASE orders.OrderType WHEN 5188 THEN 1 END) = 1
ORDER BY orders.OrderGroup

